# Count 0,1 codes with specific conditions

Tags: combinatorics

how many $0,1$ codes of size $n$ that each $1$ is between two $0$s?

$0100010010$ is acceptable but $010110$ is not.

i know it should be solved with some recursive function.

Comment: The usual first step for things like this is to work it out for small $n$ and to look for a pattern.  You'll need to do that no matter what, to set initial conditions and to test whatever recursion you think you have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously each code(I call string) should end with $0$.
second last number can be $0$ or $1$. if it is zero then the sub-string omitting last element is valid too. and if it is one then the sub-string omitting last two element is valid too. so we Have:

$A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$

$A_1=A_2=1$

it is just like Fibonacci.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:

Note that every good (non-empty) string ends in $0$ and that appending a $0$ or a $10$ to any good (non-empty) string results in a good string.

If the second to last character is a $0$ then deleting the final $0$ gets you a good string of length $n-1$.

If the second to last character is a $1$ then deleting the final $10$ gets you a good string of length $n-2$.

This results in a very familiar recursion.